# Getting 'Error loading key "(stdin)": error in libcrypto' when trying to add SSH key to GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to add a SSH key to a GitLab pipeline. The SSH key is in ED25519 format and saved as a group environmental variable and as a file in GitLab. When I saved the contents of the SSH key in GitLab I hit 'return' to add another line. When I try to load the SSH key into a pipeline I get `Error loading key "(stdin)": error in libcrypto`. I also tried manually adding a new line in the pipeline YAML by using `echo >> "$PIPELINE_SSH_KEY"` but got the same error. I'm following what is recommended in the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#troubleshooting) about adding a newline but it doesn't work. Do I need to add the newline in a different way?

Here's part of my GitLab YAML:

```
script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo >> "$PIPELINE_SSH_KEY"
    - echo "$PIPELINE_SSH_KEY" | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan $CI_SERVER_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I added the wrong key. I added the public key when it should have been the private key. Once I added the private key and added the bash commands shown in this GitLab documentation page in step 3: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#troubleshooting, everything worked. I had to add the public key as a deploy key in GitLab as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/#create-a-public-deploy-key

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this myself the last few days. None of the documentation or rare blogged solutions worked. I’m not going to claim this is the correct way but I ended up doing this:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get -qq install openssh-client)'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - chmod 600 "$SSH_KEY"
script:
  - ssh -i "$SSH_KEY" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@myhost.com "cd sites/target_dir && git pull"
```